# Best way to store order stack/queue of UIImages ios

Tags: ios, data-structures

I am unfamiliar with ios datastructures (seems a regular `vector<UIImage>` type eludes objective c)

I am trying to store a stack of UIImage object which are (annotations). The idea is that if the user hits "undo" then i pop the head of the stack and re-apply all the other images to the canvas.

I have tried a NSDictionary and an NSMutableArray but there has to be a less painful way.

These two don't appear to preserve order.

Does anyone know a list of available data structures, or could anyone give advice?

Comment: NSArray (and NSMutableArray) definitely preserve the order of the objects. How are you using it?

Comment: List, Vector, Array, ... → NSArray. Map, Dictionary, ... → NSDictionary

Comment: lol wat? Is there one with a push/pop style functionality?

Comment: NSMutableArray: `addObject:` (will be added last) and `removeLastObject` doesn't do what you are looking for? (if you want the object before removing it you can just call `lastObject` before removing it (similar to `peek` in a stack))

Answer (score 1):

There no such a data structure like stack in iOS. But surely you can use `NSMutableArray` to simulate this behavior. 
Simply `addObject:` to add at the end, and to pick up first object just call `firstObject` (to remove it `removeObjectAtIndex:0`). `NSMutableArray` preserves order for 100%.

Comment: That's good point. Then you get FIFO queue, which I guess is what the author would like to have.

Comment: Yes I would... Thanks it must a bug elsewhere with the order thing, but at least now I know. NSMutableArray it is :D - thanks guys!